# Why Was the Explainer Badge Not Awarded?

Tags: bug, badges

Okay, what am I missing?

For the Explainer badge I need:
Edit and answer 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

For [How can you use an army of dimunitive soldiers effectively?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/131322/how-can-you-use-an-army-of-dimunitive-soldiers-effectively/131323#131323)

I edited the question and it was approved Nov 26 at 18:17.  Then I posted an answer Nov 26 at 18:27 (with an edit Nov 26 at 19:49).  I have a score of 4.

The question is currently on hold but I completed these things and got the score before that happened and didn't get the badge.

I'll also note that this badge was awarded only 228 times ever, which seems extremely low to me for something not that hard to get.

So either there's a bug or there's some criteria that isn't stated in the description.  What's up?

Comment: The reason it's not common is that very few people systematically edit other people's posts. See how few Strunk and White or Copy Editor have been awarded.

Comment: Sure, but the Editor badge (doing your first edit) was awarded 7300 times.  While only 39 of those people went on to edit at least 80 times, I bet a lot did it twice or even 10 times.  But I guess it's just the way of it...I checked the stats at Writing.SE and the proportions are similar.

Answer (score 1):

The badge is awarded after a job runs, and it is not awarded for answers on questions that have been suspended. Seems like the question was put on hold before the job found your answer in there.

If you want to check your progress for this badge and its silver and gold followups, [run this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/938170/illuminator-badge-progress?UserId=54137).

Comment: Useful info, thanks.  How often do jobs run?

Comment: @cyn I got no info on that... But I believe some arw daily and some are hourly.

Comment: @Cyn This particular job runs daily, end of day. You only get question credit for things like Socratic after your question stays up for a full day, with upvotes and note closed. The edit and answer thing is similar. Probably, questions got closed before you got credit, so you are SOL.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I managed to get it yesterday with another post though.  I'm not specifically going for the badges, in the sense that I'm not doing things I wouldn't normally do just to get a badge, aside from things like logging on every day or taking the tour.  But I keep them in mind and enjoy reaching those milestones.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/131785/plausibility-of-another-extremely-intelligent-species-evolving-who-finds-the-rem

Comment: @Cyn thank you, it's that kind of attitude that makes stack sites a good place to ask and answer questions :)

Comment: @Cyn That's exactly what badges are for, enjoy :)